# Sending data over serial in python from different functions

Tags: python, pyserial

I program in C++ and C# normally and am trying to get accustomed to how python works so forgive me if this is a fairly basic question.

I'd like to open a serial connection in python over RS-232 and send data from various functions. Here's the functions that I have to open a serial port and send data:

```
def sendData(data):
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
    data += "\r\n"
    ser.write(data.encode())
```

Pretty simple, but I'd like to move the `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)` line outside the function so that I can just call this function on it's own.

Now in other languages I would just make the ser variable public so that other functions could access it, but I'm not sure I'm understanding how variables work in python properly yet. Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
def main():
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
    while 1:
        #misc code here
        sendData(data)
```

I know I could pass the ser variable through the function call and make it sendData(ser, data), but that seems unnecessary. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it unnecessary? It's the standard practice.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Compared to C++ where I could just make a static or public variable it seems overkill or messy imo. Look at the answer posted, it's more readable and all my variables and functions would be kept organized with a class.

Comment: Using a class is the same - a member function gets the instance as the first parameter. Only the syntax is different. You can even pass an instance explicitly - `SerialWrapper.sendData(ser,data)` - that's how much the same it is.

Comment: The part that I wanted was better cleaner syntax so I could shrink my code down. So now instead of having to pass the ser reference around I can just call the function, and the code is much simpler looking. I have roughly 30 "sendData" parts in my code. My initialization function calls my OptionParser, which calls another function to calculate amounts, which when finished does the "sendData" part. I wanted the serial to start during the initialization to send setup info, then be used later without having to recreate the serial, or passing it through 3 different functions.

Comment: And I like to separate functions out because many parts of my code will be reused depending on conditions, so breaking this apart into a global class allows ALL functions to call ser.sendData(data) without having to be directly passed the ser object. This way if I delete say my initialization code, I don't lose the reference to the object. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `global` keyword in your `main` function to assign the public variable:

```
ser = None

def sendData(data):
    data += "\r\n"
    ser.write(data.encode())

def main():
    global ser
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
    while 1:
        #misc code here
        sendData(data)
```

Or even better, using a class:

```
class SerialWrapper:
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(device, 115200)

    def sendData(self, data):
        data += "\r\n"
        self.ser.write(data.encode())

def main():
    ser = SerialWrapper('/dev/ttyUSB0')
    while 1:
        #misc code here
        ser.sendData(data)
```

Comment: `global` is only needed if the function wishes to reassign the variable. Reading a variable from the global scope works without any special syntax.

Comment: 2 solutions, both elegant and clean! Much better than passing variables around through function calls. Also wasn't aware of a global variable yet in python! I like the class option though. This was just a short snippet of my code and using a class allows for a lot more organization. Thank you!

Comment: i'm also in favor of the class option. repeated code just disappears like Tetris blocks! :)

Comment: @fips exactly! Also I just wrote the code and ended up using a combination of both! Created a class, but then made `ser = SerialWrapper('/dev/ttyUSB0')` global so I could use `ser.sendData(data)` from any function, not just main. Much better than before :)